# Como fazer diferença de datas no R?

Tags: r

```
dataset <- structure(list(PLACA = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("DSF9652", "EFR9618", "EQW6597", "ERB1522", 
"EWM3539", "LOC1949", "LQQ5554", "OQT5917"), class = "factor"), 
    COD_REV = c(113195L, 113196L, 113197L, 113303L, 80719L, 80720L, 
    80722L, 113318L, 80788L, 113386L), DATA = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2016-01-14 12:13:00.000", 
    "2016-01-18 18:48:00.000", "2016-01-18 19:00:00.000", "2016-01-25 11:46:00.000", 
    "2016-01-25 19:20:00.000", "2016-01-25 19:28:00.000", "2016-01-25 19:33:00.000", 
    "2016-01-25 20:56:00.000", "2016-01-26 21:28:00.000", "2016-01-27 13:50:00.000"
    ), class = "factor"), KM_ATUAL = c(52100L, 52100L, 52100L, 
    110676L, 62300L, 31144L, 165022L, 41021L, 155646L, 55030L
    ), KM_MEDIA = c(0L, 42L, 40L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 120L, 100L, 
    10L, 38L)), .Names = c("PLACA", "COD_REV", "DATA", "KM_ATUAL", 
"KM_MEDIA"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Tenho o dataset acima e gostaria de agrupar as placas para ver quantas visitas o mesmo cliente fez. Então preciso calcular a diferença entre as datas e km_atual das visitas, para comparar com o campo KM_media_dia e ver a diferença entre esses valores.
Não estou conseguindo calcular a diferença entre as datas. Esta foi a minha tentativa até o momento:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Carregando os datasets
dataset <- read_csv2("dados_atuais.csv")

dataset_revisao_km <- dataset %>%
  # selecionar apenas colunas importantes
  select(CPF, PLACA, COD_REV, DATA, KM_ATUAL) %>%
  arrange(DATA) %>%
  group_by(PLACA) %>%
  mutate(ORDEM_REVISAO = row_number()) %>%
  # manter apenas placas com mais de uma revisao
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(DIFERENCA_KM = KM_ATUAL - lag(KM_ATUAL)) %>%
  # filtrar fora a primeira revisao da placa
  filter(ORDEM_REVISAO > 1)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Marcus. Mas li o artigo aqui e não entendi muito bem o que devo alterar.. tenho um pequeno código, uma amostra do dataset, e o problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.. falta algo?

Comment: Faltam os dados. Uma imagem deles não nos ajuda a reproduzir o teu problema. Execute o comando `dput(head(dataset, 20))` (em que `dataset` é o conjunto de dados apenas com as 5 colunas importantes) e cole o resultado obtido na pergunta original. Assim, o trabalho de quem tentar te ajudar vai ser bastante diminuído, pois não será necessário digitar os dados para reproduzir o teu problema.

Comment: Atualizei la, seria deste modo mesmo?

Comment: Não, não é desses modo. É **só a saída do comando do Marcus Nunes, não um link** para uma imagem. As imagens não ajudam nada.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta, @RuiBarradas. Está tudo certo agora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `R` precisa que dados com datas sejam corretamente especificados para que ele consiga fazer cálculos que, porventura, sejam necessários. Umas das melhores maneiras de fazer isto é com o pacote `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

dataset$DATA <- ymd_hms(dataset$DATA)
```

Veja que eu apenas substituí a coluna `DATA` pelo seu equivalente em `ymd_hms` (YearMonthDay_HourMinuteSecond), como estava no conjunto de dados original. A partir daí foi só calcular a diferença em dias entre as placas iguais, utilizando a função `difftime`:

```
dataset %>%
  group_by(PLACA) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(DiferencaDias=difftime(DATA, lag(DATA), units="days")) %>%
  na.omit()
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   PLACA [1]
  PLACA   COD_REV DATA                KM_ATUAL KM_MEDIA Diferenca          
  <fct>     <int> <dttm>                 <int>    <int> <time>             
1 EWM3539  113196 2016-01-18 18:48:00    52100       42 4.27430555555556   
2 EWM3539  113197 2016-01-18 19:00:00    52100       40 0.00833333333333333
```

Perceba que no conjunto de dados informado apenas a placa EWM3539 aparece mais de uma vez. Como ela aparece 3 vezes, não faz sentido falar na primeira visita dela, pois não há diferença de dias. Portanto, retiramos esta informação através do `na.omit`.

Comment: obrigado Marcus! desculpa a desorganização na formulação da pergunta ai. é que sou iniciante tanto no r quanto aqui no stackoverflow. 

estou tentando agora multiplicar a coluna km_media pela diferença, pois preciso comparar esse valor com o km _atual.
mas nao estou sabendo como fazer essas operações

Comment: Disponha. É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo. Caso tenha alguma outra dúvida, é só fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Marcus, em uma nova extração, a data aparece para mim no seguinte formato: 27/02/2018  15:32:00. (com o dia primeiro)

eu tentei alterar a ordem de 
dataset$DATA <- ymd_hms(dataset$DATA)

para:
dataset$DATA <- dmy_hms(dataset$DATA) 

mas não funcionou.. como devo fazer?

Comment: Use `dmy_hms`, pois agora a data está no formato `day_month_year_hour_minute_second`.

Comment: eu tentei, mas ele retorna:

Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.